# The stack is displaying garbage values

Tags: c

I have a stack.There is some error in the program when I try to display the stack.
Please help me find the mistake in the program.The stack is displaying garbage values.
The stack has a push,pop and display function.I have created a menu based program.
But it is not displaying correctly.There could be a semantic error in the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define STACKSIZE 100
struct stack
{
  int top;
  int items[STACKSIZE];
};

void pop(struct stack *ps)
   {   int i,x=0;
       if (ps->top == -1) // check if the stack is the empty
             printf("STACK EMPTY Cannot DELETE..");
  else
   {
       x=ps->items[ps->top]; //delete the element
       printf("popped element is %d\n",x);
       --(ps->top); //decrement top
       
     }
}

void display(struct stack *ps){
int i,x=0;
    if (ps->top==-1) // check if the stack is the empty
             printf("STACK EMPTY ");
  else
    {
       for (i=ps->top;i>=0;i--) // displays the elements from top
           printf("%d",ps->items[i]);
    }
   }
int push(struct stack *ps,int ele)
{int i,x=0;
   if(ps->top==STACKSIZE-1)//check if the stack is full
  {
     printf("stack full cannot insert");
     return 0;
 }
 else
   {
      ++(ps->top); //increment the top
      ps->items[ps->top]=x;//insert the element
   }
 
}

int main()
{
struct stack s;
s.top=-1;
int ele=0;
char ch;
while(1)
{
   printf("enter option\np.push\nq.pop\nd.display\ne.exit");
   scanf("%c",&ch);
   switch(ch){
    case 'p':
       printf("enter ele");
       scanf("%d",&ele);
       push(&s,ele);
       break;
    case 'q':
        pop(&s);
        break;
    case 'd':    
        display(&s);
        break;
    case 'e':
        exit(0);  
     default:
         break;     
            }   

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `x` to `ps->items[ps->top]` instead of `ele` when you push an element onto the stack